# "Ignored tags" visibility preference misbehaves

Tags: bug, questions, search, blacklist, list

I just had this happen:

> [image: Empty search results page stating that there is 1 search result]

The single search result disappeared the moment the page finished loading.

---

While it's possible to hide ignored tags (presuming this is a feature), I didn't check that box.

[image]

When checking the box, the questions tagged [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) appear again.

It's either a bug against the checkbox (functionality seems reversed) or its label (not checking "hide" should, well, not hide questions).